# Is it possible to navigate from TapPanel in Sencha Touch?

Tags: view, navigation, sencha-touch, tabpanel

I am using the Sencha Touch [TapPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) and want to navigate down on a view from a view.

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    itemId: 'panel',
    fullscreen: true,
    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'fade'
        }
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Home',
        html: 'Home Screen'
    }, {
        title: 'Contact',
        xtype: 'OfferDetailView'
    }]
});
```

If the user is on the `OfferDetailView`, I want to have a button and if the user clicks on the button, it should navigate to a view `foo` and display it with an back button to get back to the tabpanel. Is there any Sencha Touch functionality or frameworks, which is supporting this issue?

I can set the activeItem to a view with

`Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(foo, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});`

but there is no back button. So I have to add it manually and manage all the views on a stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an `Ext.navigation.View` that contains the `Ext.tab.Panel` as the only object.  Then you can `push()` your new view onto that view and it will work as you're hoping.

```
Ext.create('Ext.navigation.View', {
    itemId: 'navView',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                title: 'Home',
                html: 'Home Screen'
            }, {
                title: 'Contact',
                xtype: 'OfferDetailView',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Go to Foo',
                        handler: function(btn) {
                            btn.up('navigationview').push({ xtype: 'foo' });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
});
```